# JavaScript if statement glitching

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

So I have to write code that multiplies together all natural numbers in a user-provided interval.

The code contains a test that a > b, but it only works until b >= 10. For example, if (a == 8) and (b == 9), the statement works properly, but as soon as (a == 8) and (b >= 10), it displays the alert 'Number a has to be less than number b' (even though 8 is clearly less than 10).

And if input (a == 10) and (b == 8) then statement executes even if it clearly shouldn't.

I'm hoping someone can help me find the bug in the code.

In the code there is some text in my native language but I have translated most of it into English so there shouldn't be a problem understanding it.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intervala reizinajums</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="int_a">Ievadi a: </label>
    <input type="number" name="int_a" id="a" style="width: 30px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="int_b">Ievadi b: </label>
    <input type="number" name="int_b" id="b" style="width: 30px">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick=" return reizinajums()">OK</button>
    <p id="para"></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reizinajums() {
        var a = document.forms['myForm']['a'].value; //2
        var b = document.forms['myForm']['b'].value; //4
        var reiz = 1;

        if (a<=0 && b<=0) {alert ('This interval doesn`t content any natural numbers'); 
        return false;}

        if (a>b) {
            alert ('Number a has to be less than number b');
            return false;
        }

        else {  //(if a < b) Finds all natural numbers in interval and multiplies them
        while(a<=b){
            if (a<=0) {a=1;}
            reiz = reiz * a;
            a ++; 
        }
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML= 'Intervala '+document.forms['myForm']['a'].value+' - '+document.forms['myForm']['b'].value+' naturalo skaitlu reizinajums ir ' + reiz;
            return false;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: value is a string

Comment: I should use parseInt? Not sure why, but even if I havent converted Str To Int it still multiplies numbers correct

Comment: @highzivs cause `"12" * "12"` implicitly converts the strings to numbers. `"10" > "8"` does not.

Comment: Its called type coercion, you should still make sure the data from the user is the TYPE you want the keyword typeof can be useful for that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause

```
 "10" > "8" // false
```

Strings are compared lexically, so every char is compared from left to right until the first difference occurs. in this case it is with '1' and '8', and 8 is bigger than 1. You probably want to parse the strings as numbers:

```
 var a = parseInt(/*stuff*/.value, 10);
```

Comment: This will certainly solve the issue. You got to make sure the data types you are assuming are actually what is being used. Either type checking or preemptively just make it into the type. Probably why TypeScript is getting popular.